# Delphi 2010: DLL doesn't load when executing binary from Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll, delphi-2010, loadlibrary

I'm loading a DLL using LoadLibrary from my Delphi project like so:

```
DLLHandle := LoadLibrary('my.dll');
if (DLLHandle = 0) then ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
```

The directory where the DLL resides is included in the Windows PATH environment variable. When I execute this project from within Delphi, the DLL doesn't load. However, when the same code is exectued directly from Windows, the DLL loads perfectly.

What am I missing here? I've tried to explicitly tell Delphi to look in the directory of the DLL by adding the directory to the Tools->Options, Environment Options->Delphi Options->Library - Win32->Library Path. (It feels like an utter PEBKAC. I'm anticipating embarrasment for myself in the near future :) ...)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: (1) Please show the code, and (2) Library path is the path for code libraries, it has nothing to do with DLLs

Comment: Maybe Delphi is started with a different environment where the path is not included in %PATH%?

Comment: @Eugene: 1) I've updated my question to show the actual code (although I don't think it's a problem with the code), and 2) thanks! I've had a peek in the documentation, and you're absolutely right. Don't know why I put it there in the first place. :)

Comment: @Lars: that seems like a reasonable explanation. Do you know if Delphi can suppress system environment variables?

Comment: @conciliator have you modified environment before or after starting Delphi? Environment is copied to each process on start, so it can be different in different processes.

Comment: @conciliator use GetLastError() function to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @conciliator does it help to specify the dll-path as "Working directory" in the "Run -> Parameters" dialog

Comment: @Eugene: I have at least not modified environment on purpose ... it's a ridiculous problem. I'm gonna edit the question to reflect my source.

Comment: @Jørn: thanks Jørn. I'm pretty sure that would've solved the issue, if it hadn't been for the fact that I can't easily use the DLL directory as my working directory, due to interdependencies between files.

Comment: What error GetLastOSError throws?

Comment: Your edit "to reflect [the] nature of [the] problem" doesn't really reflect the nature of the problem because you haven't told us what message is shown.

Comment: @Idsandon/Rob: The ShowMessage(SysErrorMessage(GetLastError)) displayed "The specified module could not be found.". I guess I should have added the error message in my question, but feeling convinced it was a settings problem rather than a problem with the source, I decided to try to keep my post as succinct as possible. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time, when I have a similar problem(works from windows, not from debugger), it's because of "user overrides"

("Project->Options" menu, "Debugger->Environment block")

You might have an user override for the "Windows Path" which is why it doesn't work when ran from the debugger.

Comment: yes - that's it! Simply removed the PATH override and everything's running smoothly. Why did it happen? Someone checked in an old .dproj-file. Thanks Ken!